# class name not working in button tag in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

i'm trying to add style to button using `className`in react js. but it didn't work. it shows default style like below. can anyone help with this?

[image]

here is my code.

**home.js**

```
import React from "react";

export class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.age=props.age;

    }
    onMakeOlder(){
        this.age +=3;
        console.log(this.age);
    }
    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <p>in a new component!</p>
                <p>your name is {this.props.name} , your age is {this.age}</p>

                <hr/>
                <button onClick={this.onMakeOlder.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Make me older!</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Home.propTypes={
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    age: React.PropTypes.number
    /*user: React.PropTypes.object*/
};
```

**Edited**

here is main page.

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {Header} from "./components/Header";
import {Home} from "./components/Home";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       /* var user={
            name:"Senarath",
            hobbies: ["games","sports"]
        };*/
        return (
         <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
           <Header/>
        </div>
            </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                       <Home name={"Pasindu"} age={24}  />



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
render(<App/>,window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack =require("webpack");
var path = require("path");


var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

here is the error i get.

[image]

Comment: Where is your CSS ? How are you styling your button ?

Comment: i'm new to reactjs. where should i include such a thing in js file?

Comment: It might be CSS file missing, If you don't want to use global css in index.html, you could try `import` your css on top of the file.

Comment: Suggestion: Don’t do direct binding in render instead do binding in constructor always

Comment: i just edited the Question.. does react.dom have CSS in it?

Comment: it looks like you use `bootstrap` - I also use it on one of my projects and connect it via the `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";` - look at my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily grab the button via type. ClassName did not work for me, too.
The "type"-solution works excellent for me:

HTML:

```
 <button type="no-margin">Button</button>
```

CSS:

```
button,
[type="no-margin"] {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you use `bootstrap`. if you also use `webpack` and `node_modules` (this folder should be in your project's root directory) then see if the bootstrap folder is there. if it is, then you can connect it that way:

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

if this folder is not there - then install it through the command `npm install bootstrap` and you should see the appropriate styles.

also you should add css-loader in your `rules` section of `webpack` config:

```
 rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
```

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

**EDIT:**

for old versions of webpack use `loaders` keyword:

```
 module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    }
```

Comment: it give an error when compiling webpack "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: i just added the config file to question. i still get that error

Comment: updated the answer, it's because webpack version that you use is already deprecated

Comment: now i get another type of errors. updated the Question :(

Comment: can you show modifications of your `webpack.config.js` as well?

Comment: we are close :)

Comment: you should use `loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']`, instead of  `use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],`

Comment: @RajabShakirov It depends of the version of webpack ;)

Comment: @Alexis exactly, we have already found out that he has the old version :)

Comment: `npm install style-loader --save-dev` and try again

Comment: and `npm install css-loader --save-dev ` as well

Comment: now i 'm getting another error. updated the question. i try above 2 commands :(

Comment: Look at where the `node_modules` are and if there is a `bootstrap`  folder, then look at the correct path to the `bootstrap.css` file in this folder. and see if the real path you have is the same as the path that is in your `index.js`.

Comment: if you don’t manage to do this, then there is the 2nd way - download this css file https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css - add the app to your folder and enter the path to it. Something like: `import "bootstrap.min.css";`

Answer (score 0):

Write a css file inside public folder. and link that css file in to your index.html file.

**public/css/custom.css**

```
.some-class {
         'color' : red
}
```

**public/index.html**

```
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

then use that css calss in side `className="some-class"`

**OR**

you can directlly do this

```
style = {{'color' : 'red'}}
```

**OR**

```
render() {
   const text-color = {
       'color' : 'red'
   }

  return <div style={text-color}></div>
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend to manage css files inside the index.html template, but use a specifc load and import css file in the component